# Woocommerce making sidebar appear at the bottom of the page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I installed woocommerce on a non woo theme, I wish to style it, without much change. But when I installed it, the sidebar is displayed out of any container (widgets are shown in their divs but without a wrapper). Now I used

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'my_theme_wrapper_start', 10);
add_action('woocommerce_after_main_content', 'my_theme_wrapper_end', 10);

function my_theme_wrapper_start() {
  echo '<section id="main">';
}

function my_theme_wrapper_end() {
  echo '</section>';
}
```

From the documentation, and this works for woocommerce just fine. But my sidebar is still at the bottom, without a wrapper. Is there a way to wrap the sidebar as well, and place it next the content of the shop, using just hooks, not copying any files out of the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, this is a 'framework' that works for me, in case anybody needs it:

```
<?php

if (!function_exists('custom_open_woocommerce_content_wrappers')) {
    function custom_open_woocommerce_content_wrappers(){
        echo '<div class="container shop_container"><div class="row">';
    }
}

if (!function_exists('custom_close_woocommerce_content_wrappers')) {
    function custom_close_woocommerce_content_wrappers(){
        echo '</div></div>';
    }
}

if (!function_exists('custom_product_wrapper_open')) {
    function custom_product_wrapper_open(){
        echo '<div class="span8 content_with_right_sidebar">';
    }
}

if (!function_exists('custom_product_wrapper_close')) {
    function custom_product_wrapper_close(){
        echo '</div>';
    }
}

if (!function_exists('custom_before_shop_loop_sidebar')) {
    function custom_before_shop_loop_sidebar() {
        echo '<aside class="span4 sidebar sidebar_right">';
        dynamic_sidebar(get_theme_mod('shop_sidebar', ''));
        echo '</aside>';
    }
}


add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'custom_before_shop_loop_sidebar', 20);

if (!function_exists('custom_prepare_woocommerce_wrappers')) {
    function custom_prepare_woocommerce_wrappers(){
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper', 10 );
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end', 10);
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper', 10);
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end', 10);

        add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'custom_open_woocommerce_content_wrappers', 10 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content', 'custom_close_woocommerce_content_wrappers', 10 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'custom_product_wrapper_open', 10 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'custom_product_wrapper_close', 10 );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'custom_prepare_woocommerce_wrappers' );
```

This will create a wrapper with a right sidebar. You can customize it further if you need to. Hope it helps.