# Show articles on a store page using WooCommerce with Panel Theme

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I just installed WordPress and the [Panel theme](https://wordpress.com/themes/panel/).

I also install the WooCommerce plug-in. But, I have a problem, when I try to go to the store page, nothing appears (but I entered some articles).

I followed [this tutorial](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/) without success.

I also edited the store page and added this tag:

```
[woocommerce_shop]
```

and again without success.

How do I display articles in the store page?

Comment: From what I can see, this theme doesn't provide any shop styling. When you install woocommerce in a theme that doesn't provide the [bare minimum](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30184894/629127) for products to be aligned, then your shop will look broken. On a side note, did you set up everything in the Woocommerce options? Did you import some demo products to see how it looks?

Comment: Thanks.I don't know why, but after update the module, the store page works ! Maybe something with the cache ?

Comment: Could be. Still check your settings.